# Securing Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

To configure SSL for Kafka connect REST API, i followed the documentation provided in the following link - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-208%3A+Add+SSL+support+to+Kafka+Connect+REST+interface

But still i am not clear why listener is used. Is both listener and bootstrap.server are same, because Kafka connect(producer) will be listening to kafka brokers for getting metadata and writing source data.

What should be value for listener and bootstrap.server. Can someone please clarify me the difference between them

Answer (score 1):

Listeners establish how the REST API binds to the host where the Connect server runs. `HTTPS://0.0.0.0:8083` would allow all connections on all interfaces to port 8083 over HTTPS, as mentioned in the docs.

> List of comma-separated URIs the REST API will listen on. The supported protocols are HTTP and HTTPS. **Specify hostname as 0.0.0.0 to bind to all interfaces**. Leave hostname empty to bind to default interface. Examples of legal listener lists - `HTTP://myhost:8083,HTTPS://myhost:8084`

`bootstrap.server` is the Kafka Connection string. The values for it and the listeners should not be the same, and Kafka Connect is recommended to be ran remotely from the brokers

Note: `rest.advertised.listener` is also an important setting when setting up a cluster of multiple workers

> Sets the advertised listener (HTTP or HTTPS) which will be given to other workers to use

Comment: Thanks.Now i understood. So my configuration needs to be like this                                   Worker2.properties - listeners= https://0.0.0.0:8084
security.protocol=SSL
rest.advertised.listener=https
rest.advertised.host.name=localhost
rest.advertised.host.port=8083                                                                                                       Worker2.properties - listeners=https://0.0.0.0:8084
security.protocol=SSL
rest.advertised.listener=https
rest.advertised.host.name=localhost
rest.advertised.host.port=8084

Comment: The advertised hostname shouldn't be localhost, it should be the external hostname of the machine

Comment: In my case, i have workers running in cluster in my local. Workers is a process which executes the connector REST API. As you said, Listener tells how REST API binds with Kakfa connect workers example - Listener=https://localhost/8083 and res.advertised.hostname is used for workers to connect with each other, example res.advertised.hostname=Myhostname, res.advertised.port=8090. While creating a connector, my REST url should be like this https://localhost/8083/connectors. Can you please confirm, whether i correct or not.

Comment: If `listeners=HTTPS://0.0.0.0:8084`, then `rest.advertised.hostname=Myhostname` and `rest.advertised.port=8084`, then you'd send requests to `https://localhost:8084` or `https://Myhostname:8084`

Comment: @cricket_007 do you have the connect rest api working with SSL? No matter what combination of settings I try, I get an ssl handshake failure.

Comment: @SledgeHammer I'm having same issue.. unable to configure https for kafka connect REST api. Were you able to setup https for kafka connect?

Comment: @Vignesh No, it still doesn't work in 2.5.0. They don't pick up the SSL config, so if you turn on debug, it gets no cipher suite match. I opened a bug about it in march and nobody even responded to it.

Comment: @SledgeHammer        Thanks.. I'm curious how in documentation it is said clearly about options and it doesn't work in real. I added prefix  listeners.https.* to my ssl* properties..and it connect.log file all these properties are ignored as unknown config. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect . I have also posted a question in stackoverlow regarding the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231323/securing-kafka-connect-rest-api-with-https

Comment: @Vignesh I have gotten end to end SSL working on Zookeeper <-> Kafka <-> client app as well as Zookeeper <-> Kafka <-> Kafka Connect. Those paths all work. I get unknown configs messages too, but through testing, I got the minimal set of SSL properties I need to set. You need to set up quite a few different sets lol. The only one that doesn't work is on the rest api.

Comment: @SledgeHammer my use case is IBM MQ <-> Kafka Connect <-> Event Hub (Azure) . I have this use case working .. But it don't look good without https in kafka connect REST API. :) My connections to Event Hub (Azure) and IBM MQ from Kafka Connect is secured.

Comment: Have either of you tried SSL termination from another service like Nginx, Caddy, Traefik, etc with Connect behind it?